# Solve “Attempt to invoke interface method java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.getString(java.lang.String)”

Tags: android, react-native

I recently updated my react native project from version 0.53 to 0.55. I don't know how to solve the error mentioned on the title of my question that appears in my android build. I will attach an screenshot with the stacktrace. Please could you help me?

[StackTrace error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0354.jpg)

Comment: you need to check the exception stacktrace. What you showed is not a stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your object is `null`, not much we can do to help with the presented information